# I got this error when I wanted to update my application

Tags: android

[I have uploaded an application to my store and when I wanted to update it, I got this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFnns.png)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your app was signed with a different key than the one that it was uploaded with. Either sign the apk with the same key or change the package name of the app create a new key and sign it again and reupload it to the Google Play Store.